# Preserve tags in parameter passed from xsl to c# method

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, escaping, double-quotes

I have a xml with html and custom tags in the text part, xml snippet given below -

```
<Text>
    <English>
        <p>Some text goes here with html tags like
        <span class='classname'>more text</span> and
        custom tags <CustomTag uid='value'>and
        text</CustomTag></p>
    </English>
</Text>
```

Now, the problem is threefold -

1. Retain html tags in Text:child
2. Process custom tags Text::child
3. Escape double quotes in output string

The xsl snippet used is this -

This is where the Text::child (English or other) is used

```
<xsl:variable name='stepText'><xsl:apply-templates select='Text/child::*[name() = $language]'/></xsl:variable>
<!-- This is the problem statement -->
<xsl:variable name='stepTextNew'><xsl:copy-of select="cs:EscapeDoubleQuotes($stepText)"/></xsl:variable>
jQuery('#stepText').html("<xsl:copy-of select='$stepTextNew'/>");
```

Above snippet calls c# method EscapeDoubleQuotes in the xsl to escape double quotes from the string returned by apply-templates.

This is for the custom tags within Text::child -

```
<xsl:template match="CustomTag">
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript:doSomething(1, '<xsl:value-of select="@uid"/>');</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="onmouseover">javascript:onHover(1, '<xsl:value-of select="@uid"/>', true);</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="onmouseout">javascript:onLeave(1, '<xsl:value-of select="@uid"/>', false);</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This is for the html tags within Text::child -

```
<xsl:template match="p | span">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, the problem I am facing is that tags in the string passed to cs:EscapeDoubleQuotes are stripped off automatically. If I try to output stepText directly, it does contain the tags, but stepTextNew does not. I tried debugging into the c# method and saw that the tags are stripped off in the input parameter itself.

It will be of great help if anyone can shed some light on this issue or provide any hint for a solution to the three issues above.

Comment: All code posted is XML (not html).  Attributes in XML are in the format name="value" (or in single quotes).  An attribute has a name and a VALUE.  The value is a string object in c# so you don't need double quotes inside a string object.

Comment: @jdweng Please read the entire post carefully before responding. Your comment is not addressing the issue mentioned. If you need more information for understanding the problem statement, please ask.

Comment: Why do you think you need that mix of XSLT, C# and JQuery? Can you show us the HTML result you want to create for the input snippet you have posted? If you really want us to help with that C# method then we need to see its implementation, plus a precise description of which XSLT processor you use.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to create some HTML nodes with your XSLT only to then serialize them as a string you can pass on to the JQuery method `html`. It seems easier to me to simply use pure XSLT to create or populate the `stepText` element:

```
<div id="stepText">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$stepText"/>
</div>
```

If you really want to pass on the the XSLT generated HTML to a C# extension function which replace some double quotes on the markup then I think you need to make sure you process the `OuterXml` of the `XPathNavigator` you pass in e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:cs="http://example.com/cs"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl cs">

  <xsl:param name="language" select="'English'"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {

          <xsl:variable name="stepText">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Text/child::*[name() = $language]/node()"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          $('#stepText').html("<xsl:value-of select="cs:EscapeCrLf(cs:EscapeDoubleQuotes($stepText))"/>");
          });
        </script>
        <script>
          function doSomething(n, id) {
            alert(n + ': ' + id);
          }
        </script>

      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="stepText"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CustomTag">
    <a href="#" onclick="doSomething(1, '{@uid}'); return false;">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

  <msxsl:script implements-prefix="cs" language="C#">
    public string EscapeDoubleQuotes(XPathNavigator input) {
    return input.OuterXml.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
    }

    public string EscapeCrLf(string input) {
    return input.Replace("\r", "\\r").Replace("\n", "\\n");
    }
  </msxsl:script>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

run against the input

```
<Text>
  <English>
    <p>
      Some text goes here with html tags like
      <span class='classname'>more text</span> and
      custom tags <CustomTag uid='value'>
        and
        text
      </CustomTag>
    </p>
  </English>
</Text>
```

produces the output

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test</title><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
          $(document).ready(function() {


          $('#stepText').html("\r\n    <p>\r\n      Some text goes here with html tags like\r\n      <span class=\"classname\">more text</span> and\r\n      custom tags <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"doSomething(1, 'value'); return false;\">\r\n        and\r\n        text\r\n      </a>\r\n    </p>\r\n  ");
          });
        </script><script>
          function doSomething(n, id) {
            alert(n + ': ' + id);
          }
        </script></head>
  <body>
    <div id="stepText"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works, thanks a ton ! I just had to add disable-output-escaping while assigning to stepText html element.But I still do not understand why the tags are stripped off from the value while passing to c# method. I was getting the same result when I tried an xslt template replace-string to fix the double quotes.